# Athena query issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I'm getting an SQL issue in Athena with

```
SELECT
  A_a as [A],
  case when 'sva_new_price' then sva_mv
       when 'ob_drop'  then ob_drop_mv
       else NULL end as [X],
0 as [Y],
0 as [Z],
0 as [B],
0 as [C],
0 as [D]
FROM "AB"."BC"
LIMIT 10;
```

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For us to be able to assist you, you should Edit your question to provide more information. For example, you should include the exact error message you are receiving. Also, to help us try to reproduce your situation, try to reduce your example down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, remove any lines that don't contribute to the error and try to provide enough information for somebody else to reproduce the same situation.

Answer (score 3):

There's two things that stand out when I look at the query:

First, I'm not sure whether output column names like `[A]` are acceptable. However, I'm going to assume that you are using normal column names and you just changed this to hide the details.

Second, the `CASE` statement doesn't seem complete:

```
case when 'sva_new_price' then sva_mv
       when 'ob_drop'  then ob_drop_mv
       else NULL end as [X],
```

Specifically `when 'sva_new_price'` does not make sense. The expression after `WHEN` should evaluate to a boolean, such as:

```
CASE WHEN col1 = 'sva_new_price' THEN col2
```

If the boolean is true, then the expression after `THEN` will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by John column name cannot be like [A] in Athena and your query needs to evaluate as boolean for case statement.

The another way where you do not want to write column names again and again for evaluation is write column before when and after case for once.
Also I am assuming the value mentioned after then is a column names if it is string then quote it as 'sva_mv'

```
`SELECT
 A_a as col_1,
 case col_2 when 'sva_new_price' then sva_mv
   when 'ob_drop'  then ob_drop_mv
   else NULL end as new_col_name,
 0 as [Y],
 0 as [Z],
 0 as [B],
 0 as [C],
 0 as [D]
 FROM "AB"."BC"
 LIMIT 10;`
```